Morpheme/word ratio
How is it possible that there are more morphemes than words in the synthetic languages? An infinite number of words can be produced from a limited number of morphemes, can't they?

The morpheme-word ratio isn't about the types of morphemes/words (that is, the number of distinct morphemes/words in the language), but about the tokens—the number of individual morphemes/words in a particular text.
For example, in the text "the dog-s chase-d the cat-s", there are five words (even though "the" appears twice), and eight morphemes (even though "-s" appears twice), for a morpheme:word ratio of 1.6. This means the average word in English (or rather, in this very small sample of English—actual corpus studies use much, much more text) has 1.6 morphemes in it.
